# Is it possible to avoid incompatible opaque types and code duplication at the same time?

Tags: rust, types

Different impl trait types of the same trait are not compatible, because the underlying types can be different. That means the machine code generated for different impl trait types for the same trait can be different. But sometimes the Rust code itself is the same. So without dyn traits, is it reasonably possible to avoid duplication and reuse identical code for similar, but incompatible types? Is it even achievable or am I asking for something unreasonable? I want to write the second example but work like the first.

```rust
fn foo_true() -> impl Foo {
    Bar
}

fn foo_false() -> impl Foo {
    Baz
}

trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self) {}
}

struct Bar;
impl Foo for Bar {}
struct Baz;
impl Foo for Baz {}

fn f(b: bool) {
    // solution 1: works, but code duplication
    {
        if b {
            foo_true().foo()
        } else {
            foo_false().foo()
        };
    }
    // solution 2: doesn't work, no code duplication
    {
        let v = if b { foo_true() } else { foo_false() }; // `if` and `else` have incompatible types
        v.foo();
    }
    // solution 3: works, no code duplication, but unnecessary perf hit
    {
        let v: Box<dyn Foo> = if b {
            Box::new(foo_true())
        } else {
            Box::new(foo_false())
        };
        v.foo();
    }
}
```

I looked at the Either crate, or doing something like that myself, but it still requires the code duplication, just in a more encapsulated way.

Also, this is just a simplified example, in my actual code, the `foo` part is always the same, it doesn't just happen to be the same and I think you should never copy and paste. It's okay to sometimes repeat code instead of trying to find a really complicated way of doing it, just for you to change it in the future and not need it after all, but this isn't one of those situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally don't agree, that a single function call on two distinct types qualify as "duplicate code".

However, I suspect that your actual issue is not about the single function call. But the fact that you have to copy paste the `if` multiple times. I suspect that your real code looks like this, and the actual issue is the whole `if` block being copy pasted.

```rust
fn f(b: bool) {
    if b {
        foo_true().foo()
    } else {
        foo_false().foo()
    }

    if b {
        foo_true().foo()
    } else {
        foo_false().foo()
    }

    if b {
        foo_true().foo()
    } else {
        foo_false().foo()
    }
}
```

Ultimately, you're dealing with two distinct types, so you need to manually handle that somewhere. Alternatively you can use `Box` and dynamic dispatching, but you said you didn't want that.

You can also do something like this:

```rust
fn f(b: bool) {
    let (foo_true, foo_false) = (foo_true(), foo_false());
    let foo: &dyn Foo = if b { &foo_true } else { &foo_false };

    foo.foo();
    foo.foo();
    foo.foo();
}
```

If it's because you want to completely extrapolate the `if` block. Then you could move the logic into a separate function that takes a closure:

```rust
fn with<T, F>(b: bool, f: F) -> T
where
    F: FnOnce(&dyn Foo) -> T,
{
    if b {
        f(&foo_true())
    } else {
        f(&foo_true())
    }
}
```

*and separately `fn with_mut()` if needed.*

Then you only need that actual single line:

```rust
fn f(b: bool) {
    with(b, |foo| foo.foo());

    with(b, |foo| foo.foo());

    with(b, |foo| foo.foo());
}
```

However, the first case requires instantiating both `Bar` and `Baz`, while the second case requires consecutively instantiating the same `Bar`/`Baz` multiple times.

---

While you said you wanted to avoid `Box`. You should equally avoid `&dyn` then, as both introduce dynamic dispatching.

If you want to avoid both `Box` and dynamic dispatching, then the best approach is to introduce an `enum` that contains all variants implementing `Foo`.

You don't even have to maintain all the duplicate code yourself. You can use the [`enum_dispatch` crate](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch), to generate all that for you. Using the [`enum_dispatch` crate](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch) would look something like this:

```rust
use enum_dispatch::enum_dispatch;

#[enum_dispatch]
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self) {}
}

#[enum_dispatch(Foo)]
enum AnyFoo {
    Bar(Bar),
    Baz(Baz),
}
```

Now you can simplify `f()` into the following:

```rust
fn f(b: bool) {
    let foo: AnyFoo = if b { Bar.into() } else { Baz.into() };

    foo.foo();
    foo.foo();
    foo.foo();
}
```

Additionally, check out the [benchmarks for the enum approach](https://docs.rs/enum_dispatch/0.3.12/enum_dispatch/#the-benchmarks). Because it shows benchmark results of using an `enum` vs `Box` vs `&dyn`.

Comment: I edited my post to make it more explicit, but those are 3 different solutions I tried, it wasn't my code. The if duplication is not the problem, but if it was, that would be correct. I also said that if it really was just one function call, like in my example, then that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure Box doesn't do dynamic dispatch, right? It's just dyn that does that. I also didn't make it clear but I wanted to avoid it for perf reasons equally for Box and dyn, and also avoid dyn because it can't be know in other places either.

But the enum thing is a solution to my problem, even if it's not the most optimal way in some cases. But it's a lot better than code duplication or box and dyn so I will accept it. I would suggest editing your post so that it's clear the enum approach is the solution for this.

Comment: @ihatenullptrs Yes, to be more clear `Box<T>` is an indirection, and when `T` is `dyn Trait` then you also have dynamic dispatching. You were using `Box<dyn Foo>` thus both were going on. So if we're purely talking about performance, then avoiding indirection is one thing and avoiding dynamic dispatching is another